# Pass returned values to another function in PostgreSQL

Tags: function, postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL functions. One returns a set of data, including an email address and some details about the search, to a type called email_me. Another accepts the set of data from the first one and processes it through a notification system, which sends an email out with the text and details of the first one, to the email address provided by the first one.

Right now I'm testing the two functions by copy / pasting (actually exporting, formatting with single-quotes, and pasting) the result set of the first function as the arguments for the second.

My question is, how may I evoke the second function from the first, passing the values from the first into the second?

I think this suffices as the pertinent part of the function, which constructs the different element of an email, including the email address, subject, message body, and then goes on to create a list of CC's.

```
-- BUILD EMAIL ELEMENTS into l_email
--we always want to know the primary_contact_email -we use it in the message body
SELECT email_address INTO l_primary_contact_email FROM users  WHERE user_id = l_primary_contact_id;

l_email.email_address := l_primary_contact_email;

l_email.subject     := 'Work Order: '||l_work_order_id||' '||l_work_order_name||' has been completed.';

l_email.message_body    := 'Work Order: '||l_work_order_id||' , has been completed.  Please verify and set to closed: ' || l_jobs_url || '/jobs?workOrderId='||l_work_order_id || '\r\n\r\n Details: \r\n\r\n' || l_asset_list;


------------------------------------------------------
SELECT automatortalk(l_email);
RETURN l_email;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the full error message, the definition of the function `automatortalk(l_email)` and (simplified) first function. I suspect the error originates in `automatortalk(l_email)`. We'll help you if you help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible for any combination of data types you can imagine.
Post your (simplified) functions here, and we will correct what's not working.

This message means what it says:

```
ERROR: control reached end of function without RETURN
```

The `RETURN` statement must be missing towards the end of your function. Check *all* involved functions! Now, if you already call the second function from within the first, there is no need to return `l_email` from the first, I assume? change the `RETURNS` clause for your function and only return what is needed.

So your solution could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

-- do stuff

PERFORM f2(l_email);

-- as you return void, RETURN statement is not needed.
-- Else you would have to use it - or use OUT parameters.

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Read about OUT parameters [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-OUTPUT-PARAMETERS).

Comment: I don't know if I can keep it all that simple, but there's an email variable called l_email, which gets assigned the returned value email_me, a unique type. So the first line is: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_maker_for_work_order(l_work_order_id integer, l_content_ids integer[])
  RETURNS email_me AS` and then the body of the function, which is complex, and too long to post here. Basically, there are `SELECT INTO` sequences controlled by loops, then l_email is returned, of the type email_me. I want to take that type and put it through to the actual email function that uses (email_me) arg.

Comment: @Jon: It would be better if you edit such information into your question, for better formatting and for everyone to see.

Comment: So, I went ahead with some experimentation and just before the `RETURN l_email` I put `SELECT emailer(l_email)` which does actually send the email to me, but breaks the function in an error: `ERROR: control reached end of function without RETURN`